# Trying to connect to MongoDB but I get this error: Unable to connect: Client network socket disconnected before secure TLS connection was established

Tags: node.js, mongodb, ssl, tls1.2

I am trying to connect to a MongoDB database, I have created my MongoDB account and created a database and I put my IP Adresses there but when I try to connect it with my code it puts up this error:
*Unable to connect: Client network socket disconnected before secure TLS connection was established*

I don't know how to fix it.. :/

First I tried to connect by putting my connection string into my application code. This error appeared: *Unable to connect: Client network socket disconnected before secure TLS connection was established*. Then I tried to connect through MongoDB extension on VS Code. The same error appeared. Then I also created another account. Tried the same things, it didn't work.

Comment: What is your connection string ?

Comment: Add more details like code reference connection string without auth token and stuff + details that can help understand more.

Answer (score 4):

Just do this:

1. Go to your dashboard
2. Select Network Access in the left menu
3. Select ADD IP ADRESS
4. Put in the Address List Entry this `0.0.0.0` (that means anybody can access your database)
5. Save and try

Cheers

Answer (score 2):

Ensure that your current IP Address is added to your IP Access List in Atlas. Log in to Atlas and select your project in the "Projects" tab. Then go to the security section and select "Network Access". Navigate to the "IP Access List" tab if you aren't already there and you should see a button to "Add Current IP Address". If not, click on the "ADD IP ADDRESS" button and enter your IP address.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what language you're using. But if you're using Node.js and Mongoose, add the following options in your connection method.

```
{
  ssl: true,
  tls: true
}
```

That should fix the error.